# React upgrade incompatibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting-up a continuous integration environment for some react-based mobile app and after a react upgrade, I got this error:

`` Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: EventPluginRegistry: Cannot inject two different event plugins using the same name, `TapEventPlugin`. ``

Do you have any idea why this happened and how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you show us the code that generated this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with React v0.14.7 and react-tap-event-plugin v0.2.2.

To fix this issue require only **one time** react-tap-event-plugin lib in your app, for example in your main js file:

`var tapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin")();`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer responds to your question directly, but, an indirect answer is that this error is caused because your CI is currently updating your dependencies, and it most certainly should not be.

You can solve this by locking your dependencies and only updating when you're either ready or need to.